# How to enumerate some text files using python?

Tags: python, enumerate

I want to make a program to automate excel task using Openpyxl. I am using "enumerate" to open some text files and then auto input to excel file.

```
import os
os.chdir(r'F:\tes')

filenames = ["eb.txt", "ea.txt"]

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):

  file = open(filename, 'r')
  text = file.read().replace('\u2014', '-').replace('â€”', '-')

  start = 0 
  startcheck = True
  end = 0
  endcheck = True

  for idx, letter in enumerate(text):

  if text[idx:idx+4] == 'NPWP' and startcheck:
    start = idx + 7
    startcheck = False

  if text[idx:idx+7] == 'Pembeli' and endcheck:
    end = idx
    endcheck = False

 data = text[start:end]

 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 wb = load_workbook(filename = r'F:\tes\Book1.xlsx')
 sheet_ranges = wb['1771 III']
 cell_name = 'M' + str(20 + (3*i))
 sheet_ranges[cell_name] = data
 wb.save(filename = r'F:\tes\Form 1771.xlsx')
```

I've tried to open 2 text files but it only open and input 1 text file to excel. How do I code it to open multiple text files?

Comment: why do you need `enumerate` here? `for filename in filenames` works just fine.

Comment: Because it contain error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: Hi @jodayme, I would suggest starting a separate script which just gets iteration over files working correct. Try just printing the names of the two files out without using enumerate. `for f in filenames: print f`. Once you see that work you can build up to the rest of the functions of the program.

Comment: It is not possible to have the `ValueError` as you said from your code below. As Adam suggested, you should start by checking the objects in your `filenames`.

Comment: The indentation in your example looks *off*.  `for idx, letter in enumerate(text):` doesn't have anything *in* its suite. The lines from `data = text[start:end]
` on do not look like they are in the outer loop's suite.  You might want to start using four spaces for indentation - it makes it easier to see and most Python programmers use this convention.

Comment: [Indentation convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Answer (score 0):

Relocate some of the statements and ensure statements are *in* the appropriate loops (correct indentation). I have not tested this but it looks correct.

First all imports and setup at the beginning.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os.chdir(r'F:\tes')
filenames = ["eb.txt", "ea.txt"]
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'F:\tes\Book1.xlsx')
```

Then start the iteration.

```
# outer loop
for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):

    file = open(filename, 'r')
    text = file.read().replace('\u2014', '-').replace('â€”', '-')
    # explicitly close the file
    file.close()

    start = 0 
    startcheck = True
    end = 0
    endcheck = True

    # find the data
    # inner loop
    for idx, letter in enumerate(text):

        if text[idx:idx+4] == 'NPWP' and startcheck:
            start = idx + 7
            startcheck = False

        if text[idx:idx+7] == 'Pembeli' and endcheck:
            end = idx
            endcheck = False

    # ensure this section in the outer loop
    data = text[start:end]
    sheet_ranges = wb['1771 III']
    cell_name = 'M' + str(20 + (3*i))
    sheet_ranges[cell_name] = data
```

Finally save the workbook. Indentation ensures it is saved after all data has been written to it.

```
wb.save(filename = r'F:\tes\Form 1771.xlsx')
```

---

It is probably best to [open a file using the `with` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) which will ensure that the file is closed.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('\u2014', '-').replace('â€”', '-')
```

In your example you iterate over each character in the file using enumerate to find the index of the start and end of your data, `text[idx:idx+4] == 'NPWP'`.

strings have a [find method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) that will do that for you.

```
start = text.find('NPWP')
end = text.find('Pembeli', start)
data = text[start:end]
```

With these changes your code would look like this:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os.chdir(r'F:\tes')
filenames = ["eb.txt", "ea.txt"]

wb = load_workbook(filename = r'F:\tes\Book1.xlsx')

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().replace('\u2014', '-').replace('â€”', '-')

    start = text.find('NPWP')
    end = text.find('Pembeli', start)

    data = text[start:end]
    sheet_ranges = wb['1771 III']
    cell_name = 'M' + str(20 + (3*i))
    sheet_ranges[cell_name] = data

wb.save(filename = r'F:\tes\Form 1771.xlsx')
```